ffmpeg fixing PTS timestamps without reencoding?
I have a few MP4 files that seem to have been transcoded in a strange way - which causes playback issues on Chromium apps. It took me a while to narrow down the issue but I think it is due to the pts/pts_timestamp having an incorrect value. For what it is worth, the DTS time seems to be correct. These videos will play back fine in ffplay, mpv, etc but stutter an extreme amount when playing through a chromium/safari.
The DTS timestamps are fine.
I've already tried a combination of remuxing, setts, genpts, fps_mode passthrough to no avail. Is there anyway to force regeneration of these timestamps without re-encoding or am I out of luck?
Also, if any more info is needed - I can update this question. Thought I'd post it here since the only real discussion I've found from this are years old issues opened on the chromium bug tracker.
Thanks!
Also, as an example, it seems to be the P frames that get an incorrect PTS time. The first frame in the list, the B frame, has the correct PTS time:
[FRAME]
pts=261842
pts_time=0.218202
pkt_dts=261842
pkt_dts_time=0.218202
best_effort_timestamp_time=0.218202
duration=40041
duration_time=0.033368
pkt_pos=431229
pkt_size=3468
pict_type=B
[/FRAME]
[FRAME]
pts=221802
pts_time=0.184835
pkt_dts=301883
pkt_dts_time=0.251569
best_effort_timestamp_time=0.251569
duration=40040
duration_time=0.033367
pkt_pos=377528
pkt_size=52186
pict_type=P
[/FRAME]


Please show the FFmpeg command you have tried using setts. I think your hypophysis about the P-Frame and B-Frames might be wrong (it's hard to tell). Try to examine the timestamps of the following generated video file: ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=384x216:rate=30:duration=10 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4 - check if the timestamps behaves the same as in your MP4 file (behaves the same regarding I/P/B frames).
